# WSDL method doesn't return a value in C# but works fine in Java

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have wsdl. When I tested my wsdl in SoapUI 5 response was ok. I received proper XML data. When I added service reference in C# and run methods which belongs to web services, the methods didn't return a value. I don't know why. I want to ask how can solve this problem. Can I build a xml parser? How can I connect directly with wsdl document and pass parameters and receive response?
Maybe I should change something in visual studio to my method return a value? because now method return only null value.

In Java the webservices works fine, but in C# don't.

```
 using (CCS.CCSClient ccClient = new CCS.CCSClient())
            {


               CCS.contactCenterCampaignListResponse infoooo = new CCS.contactCenterCampaignListResponse();
               string info = ccClient.contactCenterCampaignGet(token, 66).accountId.ToString();
```

info variable is null

contactCenterCampaignGet() method return null, but when i use this method in Java contactCenterCampaignGet() return 66

Please, help.

Comment: Use XDocument for build xml parser.

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Comment: did you ever fix your issue? if so, you should post what you've done to fix it - so that future users with a similar question may learn from it.